# redirectFailure google auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm having an issue implementing GoogleOauth2 using NodeJS, Passport.js and the google Oauth2 Strategy.

I've followed all of the instructions given here:
(I didn't follow mongoDB instructions,  just want to console.log the auth details for now).
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/
Under the Oauth2 Strategy.

For 'scope' I defined 'openid':
[PassportJS google scope variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LIBn.png)

The app works and it redirects me to google's login page, I can login there and it 'appears' to work.

I set it up so that when the authentication is complete the callback triggers a function to echo what's provided from google:
[PassportJS boilerplate callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54rR4.png)

The console DOES show the users openid details including their user ID, name etc in the console so the auth details are actually being sent back.

BUT... the 'redirectFailure' also triggers.
[PassportJS googleauth callbackEndpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkDJh.png)

I have no idea how to debug why the redirectFailure is triggering.

My credentials are correct, the client secret is correct (I checked by entering fake numbers and trying, and it gave an unauthorized error, but with my details it goes through fine).

Can anyone help please?
Thanks.

Full Code: (Written in typescript).

```
    declare function require(name: string);
declare var __dirname;
declare var process;
declare var module;


const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var passport = require('passport');
require('./ouath1')(passport);

export function startServer(PORT, passport) {
    var app = express();

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')

    app.get('/healthz', (req, res) => {
        res.send("TestSuccess");
    })

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('login.hbs');
    })

    // GET /auth/google
    //   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
    //   request.  The first step in Google authentication will involve
    //   redirecting the user to google.com.  After authorization, Google
    //   will redirect the user back to this application at /auth/google/callback
    app.get('/auth/google',
        passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'openid' }));

    // GET /auth/google/callback
    //   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
    //   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
    //   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
    //   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
    app.get('/readback',
        passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function (req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });

    app.listen(PORT || 3000), () => {
        console.log("listening");
    };

    return app;
}

this.startServer(process.env.PORT,passport);
```

AuthCode:

```
    declare function require(name: string);
declare var process;
declare var module;

var configAuth = require('./config/auth.js');

var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL
    },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);
            console.log("Refresh Token:", refreshToken);
            console.log("Profile:", profile);
            done();
        }
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The issue is that the serialise functions must  be defined and usable by the passport.use functions.

ie:

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL
    },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
            // console.log("Access Token:", accessToken);
            // console.log("Refresh Token:", refreshToken);
            // console.log("Profile:", profile);
            return cb(null, profile);
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
        cb(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, cb) {
        cb(null, obj);
    });

}
```

Using that as passport function solves the issue completely.